# ordenar array segun valor php

Tags: php, array

Buenas noches solicito su ayuda para esta problematica

tengo este array:

```
array (
  1 => 
  array (
    'n_ventas' => 5,
    'money' => 1250.0,
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'n_ventas' => 100,
    'money' => 2000.0,
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'n_ventas' => 10,
    'money' => 2000.0,
  ),
)
```

en donde el la clave 1 y 2 corresponden al id de un producto es decir array[1]..contiene n_ventas y money del producto 1 y asi sucesivamente.

lo que deseo es ordenar este array segun n_ventas.
Por ejemplo:
esta asi:

```
1=array(n_ventas=>5),
2=array(n_ventas=>100)
3=array(n_ventas=>10)
```

pero deberia estar asi:

```
2=>array(n_ventas=>100)
3=>array(n_ventas=>10)
1=>array(n_ventas=>5)
```

ya que el array con la clave 2 tiene mas ventas y por lo tanto debe estar primero y asi sucesivamente.

de antemano gracias por la ayuda

Comment: ¿Y qué has intentado / investigado? Te invito a repasar [ask] y [mcve]. Saludos

Comment: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Lectura sugerida.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo consigues con la función de ordenamiento de usuario `usort()` y el operador `<=>` "Nave espacial".
Para preservar las claves se usa la variante `uasort()`.

```
uasort( $arreglo
      , function( $a, $b ){ 
          return -($a['n_ventas'] <=> $b['n_ventas']); 
        }
      );
```

Se usa `-()` para negar el resultado de la comparación y obtener el ordenamiento descendente.